# AngularJS doesn't work Visual Studio?

Tags: angularjs

I have just started with learning AngularJS and everthing works great before I started to write some easy controller method and method doesn't work even i include ng-contoller I tried to include it as separated js file but that also doens't work I am new to angularJS so I would appreciate any help I also tried with notped++ to do the same but doesn't work this is my code;

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="container" data-ng-controller="AppController">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle">
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Contact Manager</a>

           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li class="alert-success"><a href="/">Browse</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/add">Add contacts</a></li>
               </ul>
               <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
               </form>
           </div>
       </nav>
       <div class="page-header">
           <h2>Prvo poglavlje <small>Hello world</small></h2>
       </div>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="jumbotron">
               <h1>Hello, {{name||"World"}}</h1>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" data-ng-model="name" />

           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right hidden-lg" >
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <p>Prvi</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <p>Drugi</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left show" >
                   This is our sidebar
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
                   <button ng-click="clickHandler()">Click me</button>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>

    <script>
        function AppController($scope) {
            $scope.clickHandler = function () {
                window.alert("Clicked");
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a `module` before instantiate your `controller`:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', AppController);

AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function AppController($scope) {
  $scope.clickHandler = function () {
    window.alert("Clicked");
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Contact Manager</a>

      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="alert-success"><a href="/">Browse</a></li>
          <li><a href="/add">Add contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>Prvo poglavlje <small>Hello world</small></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, {{name||"World"}}</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" data-ng-model="name" />

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right hidden-lg">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <p>Prvi</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <p>Drugi</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left show">
          This is our sidebar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <button ng-click="clickHandler()">Click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how does it differ from the answer i posted?

Comment: I don't see any controller construction in your post, does it has?

Comment: This works thx can you give me some more explanation please if you don't mind ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, maybe you posted it while I'm posting my answer. Your original answer doesn't contain **nothing** about `controller`.

Comment: @developer033 ok dude!

Comment: @developer033 thx man I read it I see now I am totally beginner and I have some books but It is nothing written there about this

Comment: @jhony3, glad to help :) You could follow this [**tutorial**](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00).

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the module anywhere in the code,

**In View:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

**In JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Working [`Sample`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/ap9teeLj/)

Comment: @jhony3 Check the sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the angular module. Angular works with modules. 
Controllers are part of module.

Try something like this:

```
app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app. Controller(...);
```

And use this module in your html like

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Also,
    The controller declaration you are using is old. 
Try this:

```
app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function($scope){...}]);
```

Comment: I will try I am beginner in this book I read doesn't write anything about that

Comment: I tied this newer declaration and it works great thx I will use it